# Terraform wants to recreate imported resources

Tags: terraform, github-actions

Locally I:

1. Created main.tf
2. Initialize with ‘terraform init’
3. Imported GCP project and Google Run service
4. Updated main.tf so ‘terraform plan’ was not trying to do anything.
5. Checked main.tf to GitHub

I setup GitHub actions so:

1. Checkout
2. Setup Gcloud
3. Initialize with ‘terraform init’
4. Plan with ‘terraform plan’

Terraform plan is trying to recreate everything.

How do I make it detect existing resources?

Comment: You would want to set up something like Google Storage to store your state: https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/gcs

Comment: What Ervin said is correct. The state files that are generated when you apply your configuration should not be stored locally if you are trying to apply your changes in a pipeline. The output from terraform plan should tell you why it wants to recreate your resources. This is probably because the resources that you defined in Terraform are different from how you created them in GCP. Can you post the output from the plan command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Terraform will initialise a local state. The problem with this state is that it will be available only for you on your PC. If you execute a plan somewhere else, this state will be lost. To solve this issue, you need to set up a remote backend for Terraform for being able to store the state file in a centralised location.

If you are using Google Cloud, you can use a Cloud Store bucket for storing the state file. Terraform offers [`gcs`](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/gcs) module for being able to configure this backend using Cloud Store. You have to create a bucket and provide the bucket name to the `gcs` backend configuration:

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "tf-state-prod"
    prefix  = "terraform/state"
  }
}
```